# How to parse data into link api from other class

Tags: android, api, retrofit2

I am newbie here. i would like to ask if it is possible to add data on a fixed value in a retrofit link.

this is my codes: (here i have a value that was getting my user ID from my module.)

```
public class ScheduleModule extends Fragment {
public static String qqst;
View inflatedView = null;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule_module, container, false);

    ggst = Settings.Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

and i would like to add this one on my api. by passing the data to the link but its not working..

```
public interface API {

  @GET("api/Database/GetSchedule? 
  serialNumber="+"Schedule.ggst")
  Call<List<ScheduleDetails>> getSchedData();
}
```

the `Schedule.ggst` can't link the data from my module to the api. but in my case this is what I've like to do so that in every device has a unique id access to my custom api.

this is my sample data I would like to access:

`api/Database/GetSchedule?serialNumber=5d2a2dd4c787e116`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can use query paramter like the following

```
@GET("api/Database/GetSchedule)
Call<List<ScheduleDetails>> getSchedData(@Query("serialNumber") int serialNumber);
```

and call it like this

```
APIService.getSchedData(ggst);
```

Comment: @GET("api/Database/GetSchedule")
Call<List<ScheduleDetails>> getSchedData(@Query("serialNumber") int serialNumber);     

     API service = ApiClient.getRetrofit().create(API.class);
            Call<List<ScheduleDetails>> call = service.getSchedData(ggst);


It's working fine.. thanks men